# Running two separate "Blogs" on one Jekyll install

Tags: jekyll, yaml-front-matter

I'm trying to set up a multi-blog in Jekyll one for my writing and then another section as a portfolio of sorts.

My folder structure is as follows:

[image: KT_folder-structure]

on `/blog` I am seeing posts from both sites even though I'm separating by category.

Any thoughts on what I could be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Here how I would do ...

In your root folders, you need 2 folders **_posts/blog** and **_posts/work** (note the difference with your folders)

In your _config.yml, you'll put

```
defaults:
  - scope:
      path: "_posts/blog"
    values:
      type: "blog"
  - scope:
      path: "_posts/work"
    values:
      type: "work"
```

You will need 2 pages blog.html and work.html in which you will filter posts like this:

```
{% assign posts = site.posts | where:"type", "work" %}
```

and

```
{% assign posts = site.posts | where:"type", "blog" %}
```

Here is an example: https://github.com/yafred/organizing-posts-with-jekyll

Comment: Thanks so much for the response.

Comment: Glad it helped. If you find the answer helpful, you can accept it.

Comment: So actually it prematurely accepted that comment


I can't duplicate the `_posts` folder. so split the two into 

```_posts/blog```

and

```_work/work```

Which seems to work, except it's duplicating my content even with the 

````{% assign posts = site.posts | where:"type", "type1" %}```

set out (I assume) correctly in the code.

Comment: The issue here is that blog/work are still outputting all articles (2) despite the category, type, etc.